# Proof of Tennenbaum's Theorem by McCarty

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, constructive-mathematics, proof-assistants, theories-of-arithmetic

[Tennenbaum's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum%27s_theorem) in its usual form states that for any countable non-standard model $M$ of PA there is no way to code the elements of $M$ as natural numbers such that either the addition or multiplication operation of the model is a computable function on the codes.

Here are two papers by Charles McCarty containing proofs for Tennenbaum's theorem in a constructive setting:

(1) [**Variations on a thesis: intuitionism and computability**](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-28/issue-4/Variations-on-a-thesis-intuitionism-and-computability/10.1305/ndjfl/1093637648.full) *(starting on pdf page 26)*

(2) [**Constructive Validity is Nonarithmetic**](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2274603?seq=1) *(proof is a bit more detailed)*

He is working in Heyting arithmetic ($\mathsf{HA}$) instead of $\mathsf{PA}$ and further considers the models to be put into a constructive setting (e.g. $\mathsf{IZF}$?) as well.

Below, I will list the main steps of the proof as I see them. For any $\mathsf{HA}$ Model $M$, I will call $a \in M$ standard an write $\operatorname{std}(a)$ iff there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\overline{n} = a$, where $\overline{\,\ast \,} : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow M$ is the canonical embedding.

- Let $a \in M$ with $\neg \operatorname{std} a$. One can show that it is greater than any numeral $\overline{n}$.
- There are recursively inseparable sets $A, B$ represented by $\Sigma_1$ formulas $\alpha(x), \beta(x)$.
- For **any** unary predicate $\varphi$ you can show $\mathsf{HA} \vdash \forall x ~\neg \neg \forall y < x. ~ \, \varphi(y) \, \lor \, \neg \varphi(y)$
- Using soundness and instantiating the above for $\alpha$ and $a$ we get $M \vDash \neg
  \neg \forall y < a. ~\, \alpha(y) \, \lor \, \neg \alpha(y)$
- We are trying to prove $\bot$, so we can get rid of the $\neg \neg$ in the above and since any numeral $\overline{n}$ is smaller than $a$ we get $(M \vDash \alpha(\overline{n}) ) \lor (M \vDash \neg \alpha(\overline{n}))$.
- Models are considered to be constructive, so the above $\lor$ means we have a decider which we can use to define a function by $f(n) = 0 ~\Leftrightarrow~ M \vDash \alpha(\overline{n})$.
- By Church's Thesis, the function $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is recursive and separates $A$ and $B$, leading to a contradiction.

So far this shows $\neg \exists a \in M ~ \neg \operatorname{std}(a)$ which is equivalent to $\forall a \in M ~ \neg \neg \operatorname{std}(a)$.

Further assuming Markov's Principle, we immediately get $\forall a \in M ~\, \operatorname{std}(a)$, showing that Heyting arithmetic has (up to isomorphism which is given by $\overline{\,\ast \,}$) only one model, namely $\mathbb{N}$.

I have done a mechanized proof of Tennenbaum in Coq, based on the presentations in articles of [Peter Smith](https://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/TennenbaumTheorem.pdf) and [Richard Kaye](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/set-theory-arithmetic-and-foundations-of-mathematics/tennenbaums-theorem-for-models-of-arithmetic/EEF8A22A2DBF156464F174EC467A531B), and the articles by McCarty were only a recent find by my advisor. They were not referenced by Smith or Kaye and there don't seem to be a lot of publications out there citing them.

I am wondering why this work does not seem to be more widely known since the end-result (CT+MP show HA categorial) seems at least worth mentioning. I would be happy about anyone who can comment on this result, maybe also putting it into a larger context.

Comment: Welcome to MO, Lereau! Thank you for the apt summary of the proof, and for bringing paper (2) to my attention. A further very nice related paper is [*Arithmetic is Categorical*](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~ooste110/realizability/arithcat.pdf) by Benno van den Berg and Jaap van Oosten. But can you clarify what exactly you are asking? :-)

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt You are welcome! I actually stumbled on that one when looking through the papers that cited McCarty and it is indeed interesting, especially the corollary! Unfortunately I don't know enough about the effective topos to grasp the result and the parallels completely. For example my gut is telling me that the part of the proof showing that $i$ embeds $N$ as a $\neg \neg$ subobject corresponds to showing $\forall a : \neg \neg \operatorname{std}(e)$, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt I guess what I am asking with my post (and maybe I should make this explicit) is: Why is this result not more widely known? It was published before the article of e.g. Smith and was not mentioned there. But the head news "HA is categorial" seems so notable, even if this is only the case in constructive logic which might still be a bit niche. I'm kind of looking for reassurance on the result.

Comment: @Lereau: what is $i$ in your second comment above?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I am refering to the embeding $i : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$ used in (Proof of Th.0.1 of) the paper [Arithmetic is Categorical](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~ooste110/realizability/arithcat.pdf) linked by Ingo Blechschmidt.

Comment: @MattF. The equivalence is indeed a theorem. The bullet points derived $\neg \exists a \in M \neg \mathsf{std}(a)$. I edited to text to clarify this.

Comment: "HA categorial" in the last paragraph should be "HA + CT categorical". This result is indeed well worth mentioning but this is really just a different reading of Tennenbaum's Theorem.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais You are indeed correct, CT should definitely not be left out.